# How to retrieve image into the jsp from the google app engine(java)

Tags: java, google-app-engine, image-uploading, blobstore

I am looking for retreiving the image into the jsp.

I found [this link](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/blobstore/overview#Complete_Sample_App).

But in this i am not able to retreive the image into my desired jsp, it is just displaying the image

Comment: can you please clarify you need to download it or you need to display it on your JSP.

Comment: No I dont want to download it. Just i want to use the image into my jsp

Comment: Means you want to display it on the UI. If so I have provided you a solution below.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to serve Image from Blobstore as an Image Service, It will give your image better performance, sizes etc.

See my Code Below.

```
ImagesService services = ImagesServiceFactory.getImagesService();
ServingUrlOptions serve = ServingUrlOptions.Builder.withBlobKey(blobKey);    // Blobkey of the image uploaded to BlobStore.
String url = services.getServingUrl(serve);
```

You will get the URL for the image which you can easily put in the Image tag of HTML.

```
<img src="url" />
```

More you can learn about image service of AppEngine from here. [GAE Image Services](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/images/overview)

Comment: OP is already doing this - he obviously managed to display the image.